# How to find the use of default tables available in drupal

Tags: drupal

How can I able to find the usage of default tables available in drupal.

Is there any documentation available?

For example: there is a table called node. I need to know what is the usage of it and how it acts.

Any suggestions or answers will be helpful and grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear (the term "usage" is quite ambiguous), but you could install the Devel module. After setting it up it will show, for every page loaded (home page included), which SQL queries are run.

Comment: At first thanks for your reply claudio... In my question the term "usage" means to : for example every default tables which are available in drupal should have default characteristics. My need is to know what is the purpose for that table. In what case it it will be used...

Comment: Ah OK. I did not find anything fresh (D7 is quite new, at the moment). I suppose that this formation definitely lacks. This document is the only nearly complete I've found http://contentment.org/2007/04/drupal-database-tables.html  HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot claudio... Its helps me a lot... many thanks again... But i need something the description of all tables related to drupal 6

Answer (score 2):

Every module can add tables to the database. A *default* Drupal install uses core modules, either required ones or those installed as dependencies of the default installation profile. These modules install their own tables.

Each module declares its tables in its implementation of [hook_schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7). The [Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) module use the information from the implementations of this hook to provide a schema documentation.

Most of the time, you shouldn't directly access the database but use the API provided by the modules managing the data. Tables are usually considered *private* for their modules. New release of a module may change its schema in an incompatible way. Using API is much safer. Unfortunately, sometimes  database access is the only option. In these cases, implementation of a *data access layer* between your code and the database is advised.